Running dockerized Web API from Visual Studio
I've created a simple default Web API project called ws-1 which hosts the default created Weather API, and I added Docker support for it. It added a default dockerfile and launchSettingsentry. When I start debugging from within Visual Studio, everything works fine, and I also see the created container instance in Docker dashboard as shown here:

Here is my container overview in Visual Studio:

But when I stop the container from within Visual Studio (by pressing the red square as mentioned in the image above), then the process stops in Visual Studio, but when I look at the Docker dashboard, the container seems to be still running:

When I navigate to the URL, in my case http://localhost:32773/swagger, the site however doesn't respond.
My question is: why is the container still up and running in Docker, but not available anymore when navigating to the url?

What http status code you get when access the http://localhost:32773/swagger url ?

And you also can check the code in program.cs.
